# Having trouble looping my program through a string to translate it from english to Pig Latin

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having trouble creating a program that converts each word to Pig Latin. This version removes the first letter and places it at the end of the word. Then attaches the string "AY " to the word. I am new to coding and am having difficulty making it go through each word in the string. I can get it to translate the first word but not the rest. How can I make it go through the rest of the string? 
Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string engSentence = "I SLEPT MOST OF THE NIGHT";
    string pigLatin = "";
    string pigEnd = "AY ";
    string str, str2;
    int i = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end;
    bool isContinue = true;

while (isContinue)
{
    if (engSentence.find(" "))
    {
        end = engSentence.find(" ") - 1;
        str = engSentence.substr(start + 1, (end - start));
        str2 = engSentence.substr(start, 1);
        pigLatin += str + str2 + pigEnd;
        start = end + 1;
    }

    if (engSentence.find("\0"))
    {
        end = engSentence.length();
        str = engSentence.substr(start + 1, (end - start));
        str2 = engSentence.substr(start, 1);
        pigLatin += str + str2 + pigEnd;
        start = end + 1;
    }

    if (start = engSentence.length())
    {
        isContinue = false;
    }
} 

cout << engSentence << endl;

cout << pigLatin << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using debugger is the most powerful learning tool. Try to get used to it.

You have some logic mistakes that prevent your code from running correctly.

1- Replace:

```
engSentence.find(" ")  // always return the first " " of the engSentence
```

with

```
engSentence.find(" ",start)  // returns next " "
```

2- if found, `find` will return the position of the `" "`, otherwise it returns `string::npos`. [What is it?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/)

3- Add `2` to `end` to get the new `start` as follows:

```
start = end + 1;  // start positioned on " " position
```

with

```
start = end + 2;  // start positioned on the first letter of the next word
```

4- you can eliminate excessive and unneeded code.

Replace your `while` block with the following code based on yours:

```
do
{
        // if space not found then set the loop exit flag.
        if (engSentence.find(" ",start) == string::npos)
            isContinue = false; 

        end = engSentence.find(" ",start) - 1;
        str = engSentence.substr(start + 1, (end - start));
        str2 = engSentence.substr(start, 1);
        pigLatin += str + str2 + pigEnd;
        start = end + 2; // +2 instead of +1 to bypass the space.

} while(isContinue);
```

This is not the perfect code. You can do this in much more efficient ways. However, this a quick work based on your code to give you the chance to recognize the mistakes in your original logic.

Comment: Thank you for the help, It is much appreciated. I am well aware that it is not the ideal way, but how does it change and add the ending to the last word of the string? It doesn't end with a space but with a null?

Comment: @Arty: because when `if` checks and find `null` terminator instead of `space` all it does is setting`isContinue` to `false`. After the `if` statement the execution continues to process the last word before reaching `while` where it exists the loop. Note that `if` has only one statement. other instructions are not part of the `if`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a compact version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    std::string str = "I SLEPT MOST OF THE NIGHT";
    std::string str2, word;

    std::stringstream ss(str);
    while (std::getline(ss, word, ' ')) {
        word.push_back(word.front());
        str2 += word.substr(1) + "AY ";
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```